# use gruntjs in root file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, commonjs

```
my file tree
|-  root
|-- gruntfile.js
|-- package.json
|-- lib (jQuery & other)
|-- webapp
|---- App-1
|------- src(app src)
|---------- js
|---------- css
|---------- images
|------- package.json(use to require other modules)
|---- App-2
|------- src(app src)
|---------- js
|---------- css
|---------- images
|------- package.json(use to require other modules)
... ...
|---- App-n
```

In my file system,most app use a same task.Make gruntfile in every "App" file is not easy.
so,how can i use a gruntfile on "root",and use it on my "App" file?

thanks~:)

Answer (score 0):

Unless all your apps are going to be exactly the same, **use a new gruntfile for each app**. I'm guessing each of your apps will all be different as you've duplicated the `src` folder within each in anticipation.

I don't recommend a global dependency setup. As time goes on, each of your apps will diverge and the amount of your apps will increase. When it comes time to upgrade jQuery or any other dependency in your `root/lib` folder... you will be forced to **upgrade every single app**.

The small convenience now is totally not worth it later.

Instead, just install everything locally and then you can upgrade each app as needed without breaking the other apps. If you come across duplicate code in your apps, consider moving it into a module. Create your module just like another app, then type `npm link` to make it installable. Then in each of your apps do `npm link mymodule` to install your module to the `node_modules/mymodule` folder. Here is an example file tree:

```
my file tree
|-  root
|-- devmodules
|---- mymodule
|------ index.js
|------ package.json
|-- webapps
|---- App-1
|------- src(app src)
|---------- js
|---------- css
|---------- images
|------- node_modules (jQuery & other)
|------- Gruntfile.js
|------- package.json(use to require other modules)
|---- App-2
|------- src(app src)
|---------- js
|---------- css
|---------- images
|------- node_modules (jQuery & other)
|------- Gruntfile.js
|------- package.json(use to require other modules)
... ...
|---- App-n
```